# El acortador de rutas de Typescript no me funciona

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

He visto buenas prácticas en Angular para importar algunas cosas que están embebidas en otras carpetas.

Tengo esta estructura en mi aplicación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y he añadido el shorthand en `tsconfig.base.json`

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["src/app/components/*"],
      "@views/*": ["src/app/views/*"]
    },
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Cuando intento importar desde el shorthand VSCode si me lo marca

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando termino de seleccionar esa instrucción Intellisense me deja de ayudar. De hecho cuando importo por ejemplo `sky-header.module` me avienta lo siguiente

```
import { SkyHeaderModule } from '@components/sky-header/sky-header.module';

Cannot find module '@components/sky-header/sky-header.module' or its corresponding type declarations.ts
```

Aclaro que el archivo si existe.

```
import { SkyHeaderModule } from '../../components/sky-header/sky-header.module';
```

Así si funciona

Estas son las versiones que uso actualmente

- Angular CLI: 10.0.8
- Node: 12.18.0
- OS: linux x64
- Typescript: 4.1.3

¿Qué me está faltando?

Comment: Ya intentaste hacerlo desde el app,  `"@components/*": ["app/components/*"],` y reiniciar tu IDE?

Comment: Existe un [bug reportado (_y cerrado_)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19113) similar a lo que te pasa.

Comment: pudiste solucionar el problema?

Comment: Nop, @Marcos mandó un post donde estaba bug, pero he visto muchos tutoriales que la gente lo hace, eso me hace pensar que no está tan bug del todo.

Comment: prueba iniciarlo con el / o el ./ en tu ruta del archivo y prueba a ver si te funciona. Es decir: "@components/*": ["/src/app/components/*"] o "@components/*": ["./src/app/components/*"]

Comment: ¿El error es sólo del IDE o al compilar tampoco funciona?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partiendo de una instalación en limpio y añadiendo sólo los dos componentes que mencionas, me funciona sin problemas. Quizás te pueda faltar en el `tsconfig` ajustar lo siguiente:

- Indicar el `baseUrl` para que resuelva a nivel de carpeta `src` en lugar de en raíz
- Añadir un `path` para `@angular`

Ejemplo de lo que he cambiado con respecto a los valores por defecto:

```
"baseUrl": "./src",
"paths": {
  "@angular/*": [ "../node_modules/@angular/*" ],
  "@components/*": ["app/components/*"],
},
```

Con esa configuración, no me aparecen problemas en el editor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que te sirva, cualquier duda puedes utilizar los comentarios.

Comment: Creo que si era la configuración del baseUrl. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido :)